# Laravel Specifying a condition for a morphMany collection

Tags: laravel, polymorphic-associations, relationships

I have the following Eloquent relationship

```
class Broker extends Eloquent{

    public function configurable(){
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class ProductConfiguration extends Eloquent{

    public function productConfigurations()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Excel\Products\ProductConfiguration','configurable');
    }
}
```

I can very easily find all the ProductConfigurations that belong to a Broker by doing this:

```
    $broker = Broker::find($id);
    $productConfigurations = $broker->productConfigurations;
```

What I am unclear about though is how to specify conditions for the ProductConfigurations, so if my ProductConfiguration has a `type` field, something like:

```
    $broker = Broker::find($id);
    $productConfigurations = $broker->productConfigurations->where('type' = 'reg');
```

Checking the documentation I can't exactly find how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, must just have had a temporary brain freeze or something, it was as easy as this:

```php
$broker = Broker::find($id);    
$configurations = $broker->productConfigurations()
     ->where('type',$type)
     ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it another way,
**Note that**

```
morphMany(),hasOn(),hasMany()
```

and other relation methods are all returning an instance of

```
\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\
```

That means you can use this code,

```
 public function productConfigurations()
{
    $relation= $this->morphMany('Excel\Products\ProductConfiguration','configurable');
    **return $relation->->where('type',$type);**
```

}